# display German special characters correctly in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-2007

I need to display German special characters correctly in Delphi 2007 as for now I get characters like this "ü" appear like "?" in label components

any advise

Thanks

Comment: How do you put the "ü" character in the Label? Do you put it there using Object Inspector at design time? Do you assign a constant? Read it from a stream? Read it from a database?

Comment: +1 to @David's. To us Europeans Unicode makes *a lot of sense*, because for most of us English is not the native language. Not to mention there's an enormous chance of having to deal with text (or at least names) in other European languages, besides your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Unexpected question mark (`?`) shows up when text goes trough a code page conversion that fails.

Since Delphi 2007 is not Unicode Enabled, your label's `Caption` is an `AnsiString`. The text you're putting in there goes trough at least one code page conversion that fails, and you'll have to figure out where the conversion takes place and why it's failing.

Common causes for code page conversions:

- The text for your `Label` comes from the DFM (you wrote it in Object Inspector). Your machine and the test machine both use different "default code pages for non-Unicode applications". You should *never* see this while testing on your machine.
- The text for your Label came from a database, and either the database has the wrong code page or your test machine has the wrong code page: when Delphi helpfully tries to convert the code page, it fails.
- The Character Set property of your Label's font is wrong.

---

Here's a bit of code to put the `ü` character in a Label for testing. The code selects the `EASTEUROPE_CHARSET` so I know I'm dealing with [code page 1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250). I'm doing so because the other Charset constants either select unusable code pages (that don't include the "ü") or select a code page that depends on the OS (ie: no actual change).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Font.Charset := EASTEUROPE_CHARSET;
  Label1.Caption := Char(252);
end;
```

Comment: both my PC and the test PC display "?" I run English windows XP professional should I install the German language on the windows ?

Comment: tried already to change the Character Set property of the font but this never work - I use object inspector to assign the text

Comment: Give my code a try, see if you get an "ü" character at runtime.

Comment: @Cosmin OP wants German characters. Isn't that 1252 and Western European?

Comment: actually the character appear normall in ansi or easteurope the problem is from the the translation file some words appear like this HINZUFـGEN the letter "ـ" should be "ü", right ?

Comment: @David, according to Wikipedia 1250 can also be used for the German language. I wanted a "level playing field": you can use Font.Charset to select Easteurpean, several variants of oriental or a couple of system-defaults. System-defaults can't cut it because I don't know the user's defaults. EASTEUROPE_CHARSET was the only choice.

Comment: @David, given an *unknown* system, how do you specify your TFont should display using Codepage 1252? (unknown != German Windows).

Comment: @David Can you send some of your sanity and buy Delphi XE for my client ? :)